# Jasmine - testing execCommand

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test my Angular application with jasmine, where a component has a click-and-copy functionallity.

```
it('Should copy value to cilpboard', () => {
  ...
  spyOn(document, 'execCommand').and.callThrough();
  // element.querySelector('#copy').click();
  // expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('copy');
});
```

But every time I ran my test I get the following error:

> spyOn : execCommand() method does not exist

I didn't declare "document" in any place, I just called it here directlly.

Comment: Try `const spyExecCommand = spyOn(document, 'execCommand').and.callThrough(); expect(spyExecCommand ).toHaveBee...`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute the command on the document instead of the element. I know you have commented that code in above snippet, but still, if the document doesn't get the command, can you try that and test

```
 document.querySelector('#copy').click();
```

And then expect

```
expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('copy');
```

**Note**: You should have an element with id copy on your document while this test runs. I am not sure if it gets created from your component, if not please createElement and append to dom

Comment: I tried that but still doesn't recognize command, maybe is a problem with the package of my project

Comment: try consoling  document.querySelector('#copy') and check if your spec has #copy id -element